# What's the most efficient way to structure a 2-dimensional MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have a MySQL database with the following tables and fields:

- Student (id)
- Class (id)
- Grade (id, student_id, class_id, grade)

The student and class tables are indexed on id (primary keys). The grade table is indexed on id (primary key) and student_id, class_id and grade.

I need to construct a query which, given a class ID, gives a list of all other classes and the number of students who scored more in that other class.

Essentially, given the following data in the grades table:

```
student_id | class_id | grade
--------------------------------------
1          | 1        | 87
1          | 2        | 91
1          | 3        | 75
2          | 1        | 68
2          | 2        | 95
2          | 3        | 84
3          | 1        | 76
3          | 2        | 88
3          | 3        | 71
```

Querying with class ID 1 should yield:

```
class_id | total
-------------------
2        | 3
3        | 1
```

Ideally I'd like this to execute in a few seconds, as I'd like it to be part of a web interface.

The issue I have is that in my database, I have over 1300 classes and 160,000 students. My grade table has almost 15 million rows and as such, the query takes a long time to execute.

Here's what I've tried so far along with the times each query took:

```
-- I manually stopped execution after 2 hours
SELECT    c.id, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM      classes c
              INNER JOIN grades a ON a.class_id = c.id
              INNER JOIN grades b ON b.grade < a.grade AND
                  a.student_id = b.student_id AND
                  b.class_id = 1
WHERE     c.id != 1 AND
GROUP BY  c.id

-- I manually stopped execution after 20 minutes
SELECT    c.id,
          (
              SELECT    COUNT(*) 
              FROM      grades g 
              WHERE     g.class_id = c.id AND g.grade > (
                            SELECT   grade 
                            FROM     grades 
                            WHERE    student_id = g.student_id AND 
                                     class_id = 1
                        )
          ) AS total
FROM      classes c
WHERE     c.id != 1;

-- 1 min 12 sec
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_blah (student_id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY, grade INT);
INSERT INTO temp_blah SELECT student_id, grade FROM grades WHERE class_id = 1;
SELECT    o.id,
          ( 
              SELECT    COUNT(*)
              FROM      grades g
                            INNER JOIN temp_blah t ON g.student_id = t.student_id
              WHERE     g.class_id = c.id AND t.grade < g.grade
          ) AS total
FROM      classes c
WHERE     c.id != 1;

-- Same thing but with joins instead of a subquery - 1 min 54 sec
SELECT    c.id,
          COUNT(*) AS total
FROM      classes c
              INNER JOIN grades g ON c.id = p.class_id
              INNER JOIN temp_blah t ON g.student_id = t.student_id
WHERE     c.id != 1
GROUP BY  c.id;
```

I also considered creating a 2D table, with students as rows and classes as columns, however I can see two issues with this:

- MySQL implements a maximum column count (4096) and maximum row size (in bytes) which may be exceeded by this approach
- I can't think of a good way to query that structure to get the results I need

I also considered performing these calculations as background jobs and storing the results somewhere, but for the information to remain current (it must), they would need to be recalculated every time a student, class or grade record was created or updated.

Does anyone know a more efficient way to construct this query?

EDIT: Create table statements:

```
CREATE TABLE `classes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1331 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci$$

CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=160803 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci$$

CREATE TABLE `grades` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `class_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `grade` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_grades_on_student_id` (`student_id`),
  KEY `index_grades_on_class_id` (`class_id`),
  KEY `index_grades_on_grade` (`grade`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15507698 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci$$
```

Output of explain on the most efficient query (the 1 min 12 sec one):

```
id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys                                                             | key                      | key_len | ref               | rows   | extra 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | PRIMARY            | c     | range  | PRIMARY                                                                   | PRIMARY                  | 4       |                   | 683    | Using where; Using index
2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | g     | ref    | index_grades_on_student_id,index_grades_on_class_id,index_grades_on_grade | index_grades_on_class_id | 5       | mydb.c.id         | 830393 | Using where
2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                   | PRIMARY                  | 4       | mydb.g.student_id | 1      | Using where
```

Another edit - explain output for sgeddes suggestion:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 14953992 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3> | system | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |        1 | Using filesort                               |
|  2 | DERIVED     | G          | ALL    | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 15115388 |                                              |
|  3 | DERIVED     | NULL       | NULL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |     NULL | No tables used                               |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Is the sample data you provided above what your table looks like? If so, can you normalize this?

Comment: You should seriously normalize your database, repeating columns are an anti-pattern.

Comment: "I have over 1300 classes and 160,000 students" That's what databases are for and why you use MySQL and not Excel. ;-) If your query is slow, check your indexes.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk - it is normalized

Comment: @Oliver - not sure what you mean. I am using MySQL and I gave information about my indexes in the question

Comment: Hi @Jack - I'm not repeating any columns

Comment: Have you run EXPLAIN to see if it's using the indexes?

Comment: Really? Then what's `Class 1`, `Class 2` and `Class 3` then? That's a repetition.

Comment: @Jack That's not the actual structure of his table, it's his summary of the data. He gave the column names in the `grade` table at the top of the question.

Comment: @Jack - sorry, I think I see where the confusion is coming from. That sample data isn't how it's structured in my DB - I just presented it that way to better explain the problem with a sample. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with some sample data?

Comment: @pricj004 You have ***not*** given information about your indexes. Please update your question with the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ... ` as well as the `SHOW CREATE`

Comment: I just wanted to say, that it is no problem for a database to handle millions of rows. That's what they were made for. Remember - you will need a machine with a lot of ram to handle this, because you will have to keep the indexes in it.

Comment: @Barmar I'm glad that you immediately understood it =p

Comment: Updated to show create statements and explain select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work for you using `SUM` and `CASE`:

```
SELECT C.Id,
  SUM(
    CASE 
    WHEN G.Grade > C2.Grade THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END
  ) 
FROM Class C
  INNER JOIN Grade G ON C.Id = G.Class_Id
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT Grade, Student_Id, Class_Id
      FROM Class
        JOIN Grade ON Class.Id = Grade.Class_Id
      WHERE Class.Id = 1
    ) C2 ON G.Student_Id = C2.Student_Id
WHERE C.Id <> 1
GROUP BY C.Id
```

[Sample Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00473/1)

**--EDIT--**

In response to your comment, here is another attempt that should be much faster:

```
SELECT 
  Class_Id, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Grade > minGrade THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    Student_Id,
    @classToCheck:=
      IF(G.Class_Id = 1, Grade, @classToCheck) minGrade ,
    Class_Id,
    Grade
  FROM Grade G
    JOIN (SELECT @classToCheck:= 0) t
  ORDER BY Student_Id, IF(Class_Id = 1, 0, 1)
  ) t
WHERE  Class_Id <> 1
GROUP BY Class_ID
```

And [more sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6211e5/1).

Comment: Hi @sgeddes, thanks for the response. That didn't work unfortunately: I stopped execution after 5 minutes. In general I think anything which attempts to join the grades table against itself ends up taking a long time.

Comment: @pricj004 -- no problem.  I've edited my answer to include what I think should be a much faster solution.  Let me know -- best of luck!

Comment: Much faster! 43 seconds. Definitely getting somewhere. I've edited the question to show the explain output for your query.

Comment: @pricj004 -- Glad I could help.  Not sure I can think of any faster solution :D

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a try on the original data as well! It is only one join :)

```
select
  final.class_id, count(*) as total
from
  (
    select * from   
      (select student_id as p_student_id, grade as p_grade from table1 where class_id = 1) as partial
    inner join table1 on table1.student_id = partial.p_student_id
    where table1.class_id <> 1 and table1.grade > partial.p_grade    
  ) as final
 group by
  final.class_id;
```

[sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaaab/4/0)

Comment: @pricj004 Just give it a try. It is probably slow as well, can't think of anything better. :)

Comment: Hi @jurgenreza, thanks for the suggestion. It's not bad - took 1 min 46 sec on my machine and was a bit faster (1 min 37 sec) if I replaced the partial table with temp_blah (the temporary indexed table I created).

Comment: @pricj004 Cool, hope it helps.